# How to bind IsChecked property of radio that exists in different user control?

Tags: wpf, binding, wpf-controls

I am looking for the ways to bind IsChecked property of a radio button that exist in one user control to a button that exists in another user control. Both user controls are loaded into MainWindow. Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Code for MainWindow:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Frame Content="Frame" Source="/WpfApplication1;component/Page1.xaml"/>
    <local:NavUserControl HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
</Grid>
```

Code Page1:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <local:ContentUC HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

Code For user Control 1:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <RadioButton x:Name="RadioBt1" Content="Enable Next Button" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

Code For user Control 2:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,20">
    <Button Content="Back" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="75"/>
    <Button Content="Next" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="75" IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=RadioBt}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

Following the principles of [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29), you need the parent `UserControl` of the `RadioButton` to expose that button's `IsChecked` property as its own. This then enables your button that sits outside of the `UserControl` to bind to that property.

For that to occur, you will need to modify the code-behind for the `UserControl` to add the appropriate property (`IsNextEnabled` for example) and [`DependencyProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) (e.g. `IsNextEnabledProperty`) that will then map to the `RadioButton`'s property.

Comment: Thank you! Trying to make it. I am wondering if you can share with any working sample.